# how to dynamically set codeigniter library constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to dynamically set a codeigniter constructor, but am having difficulty. I have in my controller:

```
$arguments=array('login'=>'***','pass'=>'***');  ;                   
$this->load->library('mailer', $arguments);
$phpmail = new Mailer;
$phpmail->sendmail('***', 'bob', 'hi', 'there');
```

My constructors first line looks like:

```
public function __construct($login,$pass)
```

but I'm getting the following:

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for Mailer::__construct(),
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

> In the library loading function you can dynamically pass data as an
>   array via the second parameter and it will be passed to your class
>   constructor:
>
> ```
> $params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
>
> $this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
> ```
>
> If you use this feature
>   you must set up your class constructor to expect data:
>
> ```
> <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
>
> class Someclass {
>
>     public function __construct($params)
>     {
>         // Do something with $params
>     }
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

The first argument is the exact array you passed. Use `$params['login']` and `$params['pass']` instead.